# Injecting values into Hashmap using java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was able to use java Spring annotation to inject key values pair into the hashmap as follows

**validationError.properties file**

```
errorcode.map={\
  "default.labOrder.oneservice": "AAAAAA", \
  "default.labOrder.patient.firstName": "BBBBB", \
}
```

I able to use the following  code to inject the values into my hashmap as follows

@Value("#{${errorcode.map}}")
private Map<String, String> errorNumberMap;

However if I have a property file with the following values

```
errorcode.map={\
  "LAB": "AAAAAA, BBBB, CCCC", \
  "ECP": "AAAAAA, BBBB, CCCC", \
}
```

and a map Hashmap<AccessType, List> preserveMap = new HashMap() where AccessType is an enum.   Does spring has any annotation that will populate my preserveMap value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping properties directly into bean fields only support simple basic mappings between properties and field values.

Using a configuration object gives more options and can do this kind of tricks and is also more readable.

https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: It works.    Thanks Jasper.   This is a much better way.